# Error: driven via a port connection, is multiply driven

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am able to build the code in modelsim but, when simulation getting below error:

1. `addr_x, driven via port connection, is multiply driven (44) Line :49`
2. `addr_f, driven via port connection, is multiply driven (46) Line :49`
3. `s_ready_x, driven via port connection, is multiply driven (44) Line :49`
4. `s_ready_f, driven via port connection, is multiply driven (46) Line :49`

How can I resolve this? (system verilog)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no simple<sup>*</sup> fix: You have to change your design. You might even have to go "back to the drawing board" and fundamentally change your design.

In each of the `ctrlpath..`, modules you output an address. Thus you drive the same net from different outputs. You somehow have to distinguish which of those you are really going to need. Thus you need to add a multiplexer which 'knows' which on to pick.

The "multiple driven" error is a recurring question appearing on Stack Overflow and Electrical engineering. What you have done is connecting multiple output ports together. In electrical engineering we call this 'shorting outputs together'. The term **shorting** is important as it is effectively a short circuit. This is the equivalent circuit:

[image]

Some outputs will be high and others are low. The ones which are high will try to drive the output high opening a current path from the VCC to the output pin. The ones which are low will try to drive the output low. They open a current path from the output to ground. Together they form a short circuit between your VCC and ground.

<sup>*</sup><sub>Do not think you can easily solve this with tri-state drivers. Theoretical it may seem possible, practically you really, really don't want that.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Here is one of the messages from VCS compilation:

Error-[ICSD] Illegal combination of drivers
design.sv, 38
  Illegal combination of structural drivers.
  Variable "**s_ready_x**" is driven by multiple structural drivers.
  This variable is declared at
  "design.sv", 38: logic s_ready_x;
  The first driver is at "**design.sv", 50**: ctrlpatho c( .clk (clk),  .reset 
  (reset),  .wr_done_f (wr_done_f),  .wr_done_x (wr_done_x),  .addr_x 
  (addr_x),  .addr_f (addr_f),  .m_valid_y (m_valid_y),  .c ...
  The second driver is at "**design.sv", 45**: ctrlpathx x( .clk (clk),  .reset 
  (reset),  .s_ready_x (s_ready_x),  .addr_x (addr_x),  .wr_done_x 
  (wr_done_x),  .wr_en_x (wr_en_x),  .s_valid_x (s_valid_x));

it just propagates the issue to the top-level module, but gives correct locations of the drivers.

The problem is, that both `ctrlpathf` and `ctrlpatho` drive the same signal with `output` ports. The rule of thumb is:

> you cannot drive the same variable with multiple drivers.

System verilog just adds this requirement to the standard and it gets checked for the specific system verilog blocks.

To fix it

1. you need to review your program, in case you just made a mistake.
2. verilog allows you to multiply drive `net` types and defines rules for the results. If you really want to have multiple drivers, you would need to declare those ports as `wires` or similar and change the code to reflect it. They can be multiply driven with the `assign` statements.